# What does $O(N)$ mean in this article and how does it imply this lemma?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis

In this [article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2046117?seq=1) the author proves the following lemma:

**LEMMA:** $\forall N \in \Bbb N$, there exists $v=v_N$ with compact support so that
$$[M_S(M_S v)^\delta(x)]^{1/\delta} \geq c_\delta NM_S v(x), \forall x \in [0,1]^2.$$

Here  $M_S$ is the strong maximal operator (averages on rectangles in $\Bbb R^2$), $\delta >0$ and $c_\delta$ is a constant that depends on $\delta$.

In order to prove it, for all $k, j \in \Bbb Z$, the author defines $Q_{k,j}$ as the unit square with lower left corner at the point $(k,j)$ and for $k=1,2,\ldots, N$, $d_k$ is the integral part of $2^k/k$. Then he defines
$$v(x)=v_N(x)=\sum_{1 \leq k \leq N} 2^k \chi_{Q_{k,d_k}}(x),$$
and proves that $M_S v(x) \leq 2$ $\forall x \in [0,1]^2$ and that $f=M_S v(x) \geq k/2$ on $Q_{k,j}$ for $j=1,2,\ldots N$ provided that $k \geq 2 \log_2 N$. Finally, he takes the square $R=[0,N+1]^2$ and he obtains that for all $x \in [0,1]^2$,
$$[M_S(M_S v)^\delta (x)]^{1/\delta} \geq [M_S(f)^\delta ((0,0))]^{1/\delta} \geq \left( |R|^{-1} \int_R (f)^\delta dy \right)^{1/\delta} \geq c \left[ (N+1)^{-2} \sum_{2 \log_2 N \leq k \leq N} N(k)^\delta \right]^{1/\delta}=O(N).$$

Using [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiple_variables) of the big O notation, $O(N)$ means that $|O(N)| \leq CN$ for all $x$ such that $x_i$ is sufficiently for some $i$.

I really don't see why the quantity on the left is in $O(N)$ nor why this implies the lemma of the article.

**Note:** I reposted the question in order to improve it.

Comment: I assume they mean $\Omega(N)$ rather than $O(N)$, as it is supposed to be a lower bound. But I have no idea about the rest.

Comment: What is $N(k)$?

Comment: Please cease and desist making edits that insert and remove a single character.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Why?

Comment: The only reason for doing that is to bump your question to the top of the stack at the expense of other questions also vying for attention. This sort of behavior is very strongly frowned upon in this community.

Comment: I don't see any rule against this in the Terms of Service. And by the same resasoning, bounties with the purpose of drawing attention to a question would be forbidden, and that's clearly not the case.

Comment: Beware J.Doe. Todd is completely right. And arguing that you didn't find any rule against your behaviour isn't going to help your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $O(1)$ is indeed an abuse of notations, but I personally find pretty clear what is meant by it, given the context. In fact the statement would have been crystal clear and rigorously meaningful if the author had simply written $\geq CN$ instead of $=O(N)$... This is precisely the definition of $\Omega(N)$. But choosing one or the other is just a matter of aesthetics and personal taste, I guess (for example in France we are never taught the $\Omega(N)$ notation and I only learnt it after 10++ years of professional maths activity). Anyway, as far as the "real" maths are concerned, here is an answer to your question.

Writing it as a Riemann sum, it is straightforward to check that the sum
$$
S_N:=\sum_{k=0}^N k^\delta=N^{1+\delta}\sum\limits_{k=0}^N\left(\frac kN\right)^\delta\frac 1N
\sim N^{1+\delta}\int_0^1 x^\delta dx =\frac{1}{\delta+1}N^{1+\delta}
$$
as $N\to+\infty$.
It is then easy to check that starting the series fom $k=2\log_2N$ doesn't change anything to the matter (you would get a small $o(1)$ negligible correction to the integral in the Riemann sum). In other words,
$$
\tilde S_N:=\sum_{k=2\log_2 N}^N k^\delta \sim \frac{1}{\delta+1}N^{1+\delta}
$$
as well.
Putting the pieces together, and recalling the key property that $M_S v(x)\leq 2$, you get
\begin{multline*}
[M_S(M_S v)^\delta (x)]^{1/\delta} \geq [M_S(f)^\delta ((0,0))]^{1/\delta}
 \geq \left( |R|^{-1} \int_R (f)^\delta dy \right)^{1/\delta}
\\
 \geq c \left[ (N+1)^{-2} \sum_{2 \log_2 N \leq k \leq N} N(k)^\delta \right]^{1/\delta}
=c\Bigg[\frac{N}{(N+1)^2}\tilde S_N\Bigg]^{1/\delta}\\
\sim c_\delta\Bigg[\frac{N}{(N+1)^2}N^{1+\delta}\Bigg]^{1/\delta}\\
 \sim c_\delta N \geq c_\delta\frac{N}{2}2
\geq c'_\delta N M_Sv(x)
\end{multline*}

Comment: Did you use the fact that $\frac{N}{N+1} \to 1$  as $N \to \infty$ to get the first step of the last line?

Comment: yes, I'll edit.

Comment: Ok, I get it. But I'm having trouble to understand something. This proves the inquality of the lemma for $N$ large, but the llemma says it's true $\forall N$.

Comment: This is a really basic question in elementary real analysis, think harder about the first occurrence of $\sim$ in my  computation (for any $\epsilon$ therer exists $N_0$ such that for all $N\geq N_0\dots$, and handle separately the case $N\leq N_0$). In the future I suggest you post this type of questions on math.SE, this is clearly not research level (FYI: I tried to cast a close vote but the bounty prevents me from doing so).

Comment: I had already asked this question on math.SE, but nobody bothered to answer it or to read the part of the article included in the question. But that's ok, you can delete your answer so I can delete the question after the bounty expires.